# XKB keyboard remapping

Tags: xkb

I want to replace the character map of one keyboard with some other unicode characters. I did it by going to `usr > share > X11 > xkb > symbols` as prescribed [here](http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11).

I am pasting here the code that I wrote to change the keys. Later on I also added the entry in `evedev.lst` from `rules` folder. Still the keyboard is not running. Can somebody help me to resolve this problem?

```
key <AD01>  { [   q,            Q ] };
key <AD02>  { [   w,            W ] };
key <AD03>  { [   a,            E ] };
key <AD04>  { [   U0x02D0,  R ] };
key <AD05>  { [   U0924,        T ] };
key <AD06>  { [   b,            Y ] };
key <AD07>  { [   h,            U ] };
key <AD08>  { [   g,            I ] };
key <AD09>  { [   U+0361,   O ] };
key <AD10>  { [   U02A4,        U092A ] };
key <AD11>  { [   U0256,        braceleft ] };
key <AD12>  { [   bracketright, braceright ] };

//A Row
key <AC01>  { [   o,            A] };
key <AC02>  { [   e,            S] };
key <AC03>  { [   d,            U0259 ] };
key <AC04>  { [   i,            F] };
key <AC05>  { [   u,            G] };
key <AC06>  { [   p,                H] };
key <AC07>  { [   U027E,        J] };
key <AC08>  { [   k,            K] };
key <AC09>  { [   t             L] };
key <AC10>  { [   U02A7,    U02A6] };
key <AC11>  { [   U0288,    quotedbl] };
//Z Row
key <AB01>  { [   U032A,        Z ] };
key <AB02>  { [   U0303,        X ] };
key <AB03>  { [   m,            U091B ] };
key <AB04>  { [   n,            U094C ] };
key <AB05>  { [   w,            U092D ] };
key <AB06>  { [   l,            U0923 ] };
key <AB07>  { [   s,            U0283 ] };
key <AB08>  { [   comma,        U0282] };
key <AB09>  { [   period,  U003E,  U0949,  U0911 ] };
key <AB10>  { [   slash,   question                ] };
```

Note - This is just the snipped part of the code which I modified.